# Limits of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$ Suppose \hspace{3pt}that\hspace{3pt} h: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{3pt}is\hspace{3pt}continuous.\hspace{3pt} Prove\hspace{3pt}that\\h(0,0)= \lim_{R\to0}\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\ \iint_{x^2+y^2<R^2} h(x,y) \,dA$$

I assume I start off by parameterising x and y in terms of r and theta but have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: Show that the integral is bounded above by the maximum value of $h$ on the disk of radius $R$, times $\pi R^2$.  Do something similar for lower bound.  Then use the Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The comment above works fine. Here is another way: As was your instinct, rewrite your integral in terms of polar coordinates:
$$
\int\int_{x^2+y^2\leq R^2}h(x,y)\mathrm dA=\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}rh(r,\theta)\mathrm d\theta\mathrm dr
$$
and so your problem is now
$$
\lim_{R\rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_0^R\int_0^{2\pi}rh(r,\theta)\mathrm d\theta\mathrm dr}{\pi R^2}\\
\stackrel{\text{L'Hôpital's and FTC}}{=}
\lim_{R\rightarrow 0}\frac{R\int_0^{2\pi}h(R,\theta)\mathrm d\theta}{2\pi R}\\
\stackrel{\text{playing it a bit fast and loose }}{=}\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}\lim_{R\rightarrow 0}h(R,\theta)\mathrm d\theta}{2\pi }\\
\stackrel{\text{continuity of $h$}}{=}\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi}h(0,0)\mathrm d\theta=h(0,0)
$$